# Como colocar eventos em vários botoes de uma vez?

Tags: javascript

Como dar um evento a vários botões de uma vez?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não adicione codigo em forma de imagem, isso atrapalha te ajudar. Edite a pergunta com o código em forma de texto. Utilize CONTROL+K para formata-lo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer é capturando a classe do botão e atribuindo o evento através de um loop na coleção de objetos retornados por **getElementsByClassName**.

No **HTML** criei quatro botões com a mesma classe e com identificadores diferentes.

No **JS** criei uma função (**atribuirEvento**) que é chamada a cada vez que o for é 
iterado.

Exemplo:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <button id="b1" class="btn">Clique me</button>
  <button id="b2" class="btn">Clique me1</button>
  <button id="b3" class="btn">Clique me2</button>
  <button id="b4" class="btn">Clique me3</button>
  <p id="frase"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

**Java Script**

```
function atribuirEvento(id, texto){      
    document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("frase").innerHTML = "Clicou no botão " + texto;});
}
//Busca todos os elementos da classe 'btn'
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    var ev = x[i].id;
    var texto = x[i].innerHTML;
    atribuirEvento(ev, texto);
}
```

Você pode testar os códigos em https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Cara isso me ajudou muito agradeço...

Answer (score 1):

O valor no `switch case`, neste caso, deve ser uma *string* que irá comparar a `id` do botão clicado. Então seria `case "one":` e não `case One:`.

Para capturar a `id` do botão: `e.target.id`.

Isso acima é o que estará na função `tdButton`.

Antes é preciso criar uma *coleção* dos botões adicionando algum tipo de atributo em comum entre eles, o mais comum é usar o `class`. Sugiro que inclua em cada botão um `class="bts"` (`bts` é exemplo, você pode usar o nome que quiser).

Depois fazer um *loop* adicionando `eventListener` em cada botão da coleção:

```
var tdBt = document.getElementsByClassName("bts");

for(var x=0; x<tdBt.length; x++){
   tdBt[x].addEventListener("click", tdButton);
}
```

**Função:**

```
function tdButton(e){

   var btValor = e.target.id;

   switch(btValor){
      case "one":
      Result = "1";
      alert(Result);
      break;

      case "two":
      Result = "2";
      alert(Result);
      break;

      case "tree":
      Result = "3";
      alert(Result);
      break;

   }

}
```

**Exemplo funcional com os códigos juntos:**

```js
window.onload = function(){
   
   var One = document.getElementById("one");
   var Two = document.getElementById("two");
   var Tree = document.getElementById("tree");
   
   var tdBt = document.getElementsByClassName("bts");
   
   for(var x=0; x<tdBt.length; x++){
      tdBt[x].addEventListener("click", tdButton);
   }
   
   function tdButton(e){

      var btValor = e.target.id;

      switch(btValor){
         case "one":
         Result = "1";
         console.log(Result);
         break;

         case "two":
         Result = "2";
         console.log(Result);
         break;

         case "tree":
         Result = "3";
         console.log(Result);
         break;

      }
      
   }
   
}
```

```html
<button class="bts" id="one">1</button>
<button class="bts" id="two">2</button>
<button class="bts" id="tree">3</button>
```

Ou você pode usar uma outra técnica com `dataset`:

```js
window.onload = function(){
   
   var One = document.getElementById("one");
   var Two = document.getElementById("two");
   var Tree = document.getElementById("tree");
   
   var tdBt = document.getElementsByClassName("bts");
   
   for(var x=0; x<tdBt.length; x++){
      tdBt[x].addEventListener("click", tdButton);
   }
   
   function tdButton(e){

      var btValor = document.getElementById(e.target.id).dataset.v;

      console.log(btValor);      

   }
   
}
```

```html
<button class="bts" data-v="1" id="one">1</button>
<button class="bts" data-v="2" id="two">2</button>
<button class="bts" data-v="3" id="tree">3</button>
```